# Find an element with Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

Somebody can help me to find a way to click on an img with Python Selenium?

I need to find the div class="A" which has a div class="B" and then, click on his img in class="D"

```html
<div class="A">
    ...
</div>
...
<div class="A">

     <div class="B">     <!-- HERE IS WHAT I NEED TO CHECK-->
        <span class="E"> <!-- HERE IS WHAT I NEED TO CHECK-->
        <span class="F"> <!-- HERE IS WHAT I NEED TO CHECK-->
     </div>              <!-- HERE IS WHAT I NEED TO CHECK-->
     
     <div class="C"> </div>
     
     <div class="D">
        <img class="Y" src="..."> <!-- HERE IS WHAT I NEED TO CLICK IF class="B" DOES EXIST (EVERY class="A" has an IMG in div class="D")-->
     </div>
     
</div>
...
<div class="A">
    ...
</div>
```

I know I have to use XPath or CSS selector, but here it's not a rel/abs XPath... Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the element exists you can use driver.find_elements.
It returns a list of web elements matching the passed locator.
In case the element exists it returns non-empty list treated as Boolean `true` in Python, otherwise it returns an empty list recognized as `false` in Python.
UPD:
According to the latest requirements your code can be something like this:

```
a_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='A']")
for a_el in a_list:
    if a_el.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class ='B']"):
       a_el.find_element_by_xpath(".//img[@class ='Y']").click()
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify every div class="A" got an img in div class="D"...
BUT all div class="A" do not necessarily have a class B !!!

Then I need to select the IMG of the class="A" which has a class="B", I hope this will help you to understand

Comment: So, only if there is a div with class name B inside that parent div with class A only then you want to click on img with class Y inside that parent div with class A. Correct? If so - see the updated answer

Comment: There is only one class="B" for all class="A" ! But with your code, this will not click the first img class="Y" of the code ?

But I think you understood what I need, my english is limited then I hope I undestand what you said xD

Comment: Do you mean: there are many elements located by `//div[@class='A']` so we want to check existence of `//div[@class ='B']` inside each such A class element and for each `//div[@class='A']` containing `//div[@class ='B']` you want to click the `//img[@class ='Y']` inside that `//div[@class='A']` ? Correct? My English is also far from being mother tongue :)

Comment: Yes there is a lot of elements located by div class="A" !
But there is only one class="A" which contains a class="B" then I need the IMG of the class="A" which contains class="B". I think it should be better now ! Ask me if you see what I mean xD

Comment: I think the code is right,
but now my problem is I need to test if class="B" does exist... but not with a while because I use some "if" next to this code.
I'm using "if EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "B")):" but don't seems to work...

Comment: But this is exactly what I wrote. My code checks existence of B class inside each of A class element. Also, there is no `while` in my code. Also, `EC.presence_of_element_located` waits for existence of element, this is not what you need here.

Comment: Oh I see !
I put the code in a While because I want to execute other "if" around... But with your code I don't know why it's really slow for no reason. But the code worked 1 time, I think I'm on the good way !

Comment: The for is really slow... like 5/7sec by element. I put a print("test") to see.
Do you have an idea how I can improve the speed ?

Comment: My code itself should not take significant time to perform. I can't see your entire code, also not the web site you are running on, but, again, I'm sure I have answered your question several times: each time you updated the question and each time I have answered accordingly. So I'd like to close this issue.

Comment: I posted the final code bellow! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'A']/div[@class ='B']"):  # Finding the element in case it exists.
    image_to_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'D']//img[@class ='Y']")
    image_to_click.click() # Clicking on the image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help !

The final code is :

```
skin_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("B")
if len(skin_list) != 0:
     skin_list[0].find_element_by_xpath("..//div[@class='D']").click()
```

But now, my new problem is the "skin_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name" take a long time to search...

Comment: Are you sure you copied that correct? It should be 1 dot there, not 2:  `skin_list[0].find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='D']").click()` , not `skin_list[0].find_element_by_xpath("..//div[@class='D']").click()`

Comment: Yes, I realized that it was not the image but the div to click... but it didn't matter in my problem so I didn't specify it but thanks !
The site has to much information then my find elements take a long time :(